# Letter segmentation from simple CAPTCHA using K-means clustering in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, captcha, k-means, image-segmentation

Context:
I'm trying learning machine-learning using python3. My intended goal is to create a CNN program that can guess simple 4 letters 72*24 pixels CAPTCHA image as below:
[CAPTCHA Image Displaying VDF5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqBWX.png). This challenge was inspired by https://medium.com/@ageitgey/how-to-break-a-captcha-system-in-15-minutes-with-machine-learning-dbebb035a710, which I thought would be a great challenge for me to learn k-means clustering and CNN.

Edit---
I see I was being too "build me this guy". Now that I found scikit, I'll try to learn it and apply that instead. Sorry for annoying you all.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a great example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you are looking to build a machine learning algorithm for educational purposes. If so, import TensorFlow and get to it! However, seeing as your question seems to be "create this for me" you might be better off simply using existing implementations from the scikit learn package. Simply import scikit learn, make an instance of the `KNearestNeighborClassifier` train it, and boom you've cracked this problem.

Comment: Huh I never heard of Scikit! I'll look into it thank you!

Comment: @scotty No problem! I hope you continue to participate on StackOverflow!